# linux kernel interrupt hijacking

Tags: module, linux-kernel

So my last kernel homework was to hijack an interrupt by replacing the address of the interrupt handler in the IDT with the address of my own hijack routine. My module works correctly; however whenever I have a print statement within my hijack routine I get a kernel oops or panic. So I guess I am wondering if anybody has an explanation for this or if there is a way to debug it. I'm running kernel 3.0.4 and here is some of the error messages I get

```
[ 2479.355359] general protection fault: 0000 [#2] SMP 
[ 2479.356972] Modules linked in: get_idt(P) cryptd aes_i586 aes_generic binfmt_misc pci_stub vboxpci vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vboxdrv nouveau ttm drm_kms_helper drm i2c_algo_bit mxm_wmi parport_pc ppdev snd_hda_codec_analog joydev pcmcia snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm arc4 snd_seq_midi yenta_socket pcmcia_rsrc pcmcia_core snd_rawmidi r852 sm_common nand nand_ids nand_ecc video ath5k ath snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 snd_seq snd_timer cfg80211 btusb snd_seq_device bluetooth psmouse thinkpad_acpi tpm_tis serio_raw sdhci_pci firewire_ohci sdhci mtd firewire_core crc_itu_t tpm tpm_bios nvram snd e1000e lp parport soundcore snd_page_alloc [last unloaded: get_idt]
[ 2479.358225] 
[ 2479.358225] Pid: 2872, comm: float Tainted: P      D     3.0.0 #46 LENOVO 64574JU/64574JU
[ 2479.358225] EIP: 0060:[<c1049244>] EFLAGS: 00210046 CPU: 0
[ 2479.358225] EIP is at vprintk+0x64/0x4a0
[ 2479.358225] EAX: ffffffff EBX: 00000000 ECX: 00000000 EDX: 00000000
[ 2479.358225] ESI: f0143fd8 EDI: 00000000 EBP: f0143fbc ESP: f0143f44
[ 2479.358225]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 0000 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
[ 2479.358225] Process float (pid: 2872, ti=f0142000 task=f08df230 task.ti=f0142000)
[ 2479.358225] Stack:
[ 2479.358225]  f08df230 f0398ab8 f0398a80 00000004 00200046 b7651c10 c10ff884 f84bd024
[ 2479.358225]  f0398a80 f0143f98 c1100889 ffffffef 00000004 ef85e7f4 f0398a84 ef85e9a0
[ 2479.358225]  b7799000 ef85e7e8 f0398a80 f0398ab8 b7788000 f0143fac c1101c9b b7783ff4
[ 2479.358225] Call Trace:
[ 2479.358225]  [<c10ff884>] ? remove_vma+0x44/0x60
[ 2479.358225]  [<c1100889>] ? do_munmap+0x1f9/0x270
[ 2479.358225]  [<c1101c9b>] ? sys_munmap+0x4b/0x60
[ 2479.358225]  [<c1516760>] ? spurious_fault+0xd0/0xd0
[ 2479.358225]  [<c1510af6>] printk+0x30/0x32
[ 2479.358225]  [<f84bc028>] take_over+0x28/0x30 [get_idt]
[ 2479.358225]  [<f84bc03e>] hijack+0x6/0x18 [get_idt]
[ 2479.358225] Code: 78 c1 00 0f 84 29 03 00 00 8b 1d ac 94 78 c1 85 db 0f 85 a6 03 00 00 9c 58 8d 74 26 00 89 45 98 fa 90 8d 74 26 00 a1 f4 6d 73 c1 
[ 2479.358225]  8b 15 c0 30 83 c1 89 55 9c 39 c2 0f 84 9f 03 00 00 b8 a0 d6 
[ 2479.358225] EIP: [<c1049244>] vprintk+0x64/0x4a0 SS:ESP 0068:f0143f44
[ 2479.358225] ---[ end trace bae1cb37e149735b ]---
```

and here is my hijack routine that gives me an error:

```
asmlinkage void take_over(void) {
    printk("Divide by 0 has been hijacked\n");
}
```

I made a different routine to manipulate an integer which worked correctly, but I would like to have the routine contain a print statement.

Answer (score 0):

The `printk` calls should be prefixed with `KERN_*` constants. So please try:

```
 printk(KERN_INFO "Divide by 0 has been hijacked\n");
```

Yes, that's rigth: there's no comma between the `KERN_INFO` and the string.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that those particular key strokes need specific handling and by returning `IRQ_HANDLED` the kernel does not call the other shared handler? Have you tried returning `IRQ_NONE`?